# Bash: inserting output from `id` into print statement

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, scripting

I'm trying to achieve the following:
List my Linux users, that have set bin/bash in /etc/passwd AND append each user's info from `id [username]` into the print statement, something in the lines of:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep bin/bash | awk -F\: '{print $1";"$(id $1)}'
```

(which obviously does not work ;) )

I've got the feeling that I'm pretty close; what am I missing?

Output is supposed to be (see DavDav's comment):

```
User1;uid=1000(User1) gid=1000(User1) groups=1000(User1) 
User2;uid=1001(User2) gid=1001(User2) groups=1001(User2) 
User3;uid=1002(User3) gid=1002(User3) groups=1002(User3)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Output is supposed to be;

    User1;uid=1000(User1) gid=1000(User1) groups=1000(User1)
    User2;uid=1001(User2) gid=1001(User2) groups=1001(User2)
    User3;uid=1002(User3) gid=1002(User3) groups=1002(User3)

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
 </etc/passwd grep bin/bash | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -n1 id
```

Comment: Hoppla - original question modified.

Comment: use `xargs -I{} sh -c "echo -n {}\;; id {};"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 awk -F ':' '/bin\/bash/ {printf ($1";"); system("id "$1)}' /etc/passwd
```

- `system` will executes the command and returns the value to *awk*

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
for i in $(grep /bin/bash /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{ print $1 }'); do
    echo "${i};$(id ${i})"
done
```

The `grep ... awk ...` will generate the list of user names corresponding to lines in `/etc/passwd` that contain `/bin/bash`.  On each iteration of the `for` loop, `i` will be one of those usernames.  The `echo` then prints the username followed by a semi-colon, followed by the output of `id` for that username.